# Filter Facebook friends who also use the App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook official PHP SDK.

I have came through other articles that `$facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=installed,name&limit=5')` able to get my the user's friends who have also use the web app.

but seem like Facebook is giving all the user's friends. I guess Facebook doesn't filter for me who are using the app and who are not using. Facebook only pass a "true" to the user's friend data, only if the friend has installed the app.

**my problem is, what is the good way to filter those results?** I don't feel like doing "for loop" to check the thousands of results (afraid performance impact on my app).

i have seen others doing it nicely, when i connect to their App, they show me my friends who also there.

Note: i am new to FB API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code written in Facebook default web app.

```
$app_using_friends = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1'
  ));
```